# Cannot add foreign key constraint in MYSQL, can't find any error in my code

Tags: mysql

This is the task:

> Create a table `payment` with attributes: `p_id`, `c_id`, `staff_id`, `amount`, `payment_date` where `p_id` is primary key and `c_id` and `staff_id` is foreign key which refer to table `customer` and `staff` respectively. Display the `p_id` and `staff_id` from the table payment where payment_date is 8 august 2020

Please help I am getting this error even though my code seems right to me

```
create table payment(
p_id int primary key,
amount int,
payment_date date,
c_id int,
staff_id int
);
```

```
create table customer(
cus_id int primary key,
c_id int,
foreign key (c_id) references payment(c_id)
);
```

> ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Comment: `payment(c_id)` is not indexed.

Comment: Usually a foreign key references the primary key of the other table. Are you sure you don't have this backwards? The `payment` table should have a foreign key referencing the customer who made the payment.

Comment: Create a table payment with attributes: p_id, c_id, staff_id, amount, payment_date
where p_id is primary key and c_id and staff_id is foreign key which refer to table
customer and staff respectively. Display the p_id and staff_id from the table payment
where payment_date is 8 august 2020 This is the question

Comment: A customer can make many payments. Why would the customer row have a reference to a single payment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your foreign key relationship backwards. `payment` should have FK to `customer` and `staff`.

```
create table customer (
    c_id int primary key,
    -- other columns
);

create table staff (
    s_id int primary key
    -- other columns
);

create table payment(
    p_id int primary key,
    amount int,
    payment_date date,
    c_id int,
    staff_id int,
    foreign key (c_id) references customer(c_id),
    foreign key (staff_id) references staff(s_id)
);
```